# Samsung Galaxy fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(path) return NULL

Tags: android

I have some strenge problem in my application. I got null value when run this line on any Samsung Galaxy phone "fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(path)". I tried the same code on NEXUS,LG Optimus and many other phone but this statement return not null but any file type i.e video/mp4, video/3gp, video.avi etc...
plz help

```
//----Code

public static String getMimeType(){

        String path="__MACOSX/._MR_BEAN_FUNNY.3gp";

        FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
        if (path.startsWith("/"))
        {

            path = "file:/"+ path;
        }
        else
        {

            path = "file://" + path;
        }

       String type = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(path);


        return type;        
    }
```

Comment: Nobody dont know about this. No one has this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue ....

```
String type;

        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
        type=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

return type;
```